# Update Akka-version: ClusterClient is not a member of package akka.contrib.pattern

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I used `akka-2.3.9` and `akka.contrib.pattern.ClusterClient`.

Having updated the version `akka-2.3.9` -> `akka-2.4.9` I've got the following mistake:

```
ClusterClient is not a member of package akka.contrib.pattern
```

Should I use `akka.cluster.client.ClusterClient` instead of previous `akka.contrib.pattern.ClusterClient` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See [2.4.9 API](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/#akka.cluster.client.ClusterClient) vs [2.3.9 API](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.9/#akka.contrib.pattern.ClusterClient).

Comment: Thanks! Also I've found the following migration guide: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/project/migration-guide-2.3.x-2.4.x.html#ClusterClient_construction